# Setting low_memory to false while reading a mixed dtype 2.5GB csv file using Pandas is not working

Tags: python, pandas

Still Getting memory error. I tried setting engine='python' as well which is not working. Also it is taking up more than 32 GB of RAM. Is there an alternate solution?

Comment: Are you running 64-bit python, OS, etc. also I think that `low_memory` doesn't really do anything AFAIK

Comment: Yes, it is a 64 bit linux machine

Comment: But are you running 64-bit python?

Comment: Yes. 64 bit python only

Comment: You need to post more info then about the data file, presumably you're able to load the file in chunks using `chunksize` param, what is the data exactly

Comment: The data is of size nearly 2.5 GB, mixed data type, sparse data with 1183748 rows and 2141 columns. I tried using chunks, but after learning OneHotEncoder/DictVectorizer, I came to know that I have to import the entire dataset to transform from string to float. Or else DictVectorizer is using same codes for two different strings. Is there any option/alternative available?